# C# Passing a part of an array as an argument of a function by reference

Tags: c#, c++

Is the C# code below the equivalent way of trying to achieve the same as the C++ code?
Is there any way to avoid the copy (while not sending the whole array to the function)?

C++

```
static void somefunction(double* v, int nb)
{
//something that will update v[0],v[1], ... v[nb-1]
}

double * myarray=new double[100];
somefunction(&myarray[10],5);
//...
delete [] myarray;
```

C#

```
static void somefunction(double[] v, int nb)
{
//something that will update v[0],v[1], ... v[nb-1]
}

double[]  myarray=new double[100];
double[] temp_array=new double[5];
somefunction(temp_array,5);
temp_array.CopyTo(myarray,10);
```

Comment: Unnecessary pointers alert.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are reference types. You are not sending the whole array to the function: you are sending a reference to the array.

If you want your function to update only part of that array, pass the start and end indices as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, use `std::vector`, and iterator-pair.

And in C#, you could pass the entire array (which is a *reference type*) along with a pair of indices signifying begin and end.

---

C++ code should look like this:

```
void f(double *begin, double *end)
{
    for ( ; begin < end; ++begin )
    {
         auto & value = *begin; 
         //etc
    }
}

std::vector<double> v(100);
f(&v[10], &v[10] + 5);
```

That is idiomatic, and follows the Standard library philosophy!

---

And C# code should look like this:

```
void f(double[] v, int begin, int end)
{
    for (  ; begin < end ; ++end )
    {
          //access v[begin]
          //etc
    }
}

double[] v =new double[100];
f(v, 10, 10 + 5);
```

This attempts to imitate C++ style. Nothing wrong with that. However, in C#, it is customary to pass the start index and the count, so you can do the following instead:

```
void f(double[] v, int startIndex, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ;  ++i, ++startIndex)
    {
          //access v[startIndex]
          //etc
    }
}

double[] v =new double[100];
f(v, 10, 5); //note the difference here!
```

The second approach follows the .NET library philosophy. I would with this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go for this!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) to specify the range of the array. You would still need to interrogate the Array, Count and Offset properties of the ArraySegment though. Still, it provides a convenient wrapper.

The alternative would be to write a full-blown IList wrapper for the array (or ICollection, or some other collection type).